# Get code between tags and generate youtube embed

Tags: youtube, embed

I have some tekst and in the middle of article I put {youtube}IPtv14q9ZDg{/youtube}. How to make code which is between {youtube} generated in youtube embed

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP, but there might be other options.
I filter the text for the key-words. Then take the 11 digit code and wrap it in a link tag. Works best in a "for loop".

This is one I use to find url's in my text and make them live. But you can modify it to do what you want by changing the "preg_match" setting.

```
function make_clickable($string) {
$string = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/"," <br /> ",$string);
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match('#((^https?|http|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i', $value)){
        $arr[$key] = "<a class=\"custome\" href='". $value ."'     target=\"_blank\" class='link'>$value</a> ";
    }
  }
$string = implode(' ', $arr);
return $string;
}
```